# How to only read in data from below a specific string of text

Tags: r, subset, extract

I routinely work with .txt files that contain hundreds of lines of irrelevant text at the start of the file. This text appears above tabulated data that I need to analyse in R. The number of lines of irrelevant text is never the same between two files. However, there is always one identical string of text at the end of the irrelevant content and before the start of the tabulated data (i.e., "ID Only Records:").

I need to analyse/extract all of the data in the columns titled "Date" "Time" "Channel" "Tag ID" "Antenna" and "Power"

[image]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: `readLines` the top `n` lines to find your cutoff line, then use `skip=` (for whichever read function you're using).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how many lines you need to skip beforehand, we can use `readLines` to read all the text from the file. Find the line number using `grep` the text `'ID only records :'` and start reading the data from that line by collapsing the text into one string.

```
temp <- readLines('temp.txt')

output <- read.table(text = paste0(trimws(temp[(
                 grep('ID only records :', temp) + 1) : length(temp)]), 
                collapse = "\n"), header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep` with `system` commands to use that in `skip` and read the data with `read.table`

```
read.table('temp.txt', skip =
      as.integer(system('grep -n Date temp.txt|cut -d: -f 1', intern = TRUE))-1,
                header = TRUE)
#      Date     Time Channel TagID Antenna Power
#1 02/17/20 12:57:50       1    61       1    90
#2 02/17/20 12:57:55       1    61       1    90
#3 02/17/20 12:58:00       1   999       2    55
#4 02/17/20 12:58:05       1   999       2    58
#5 02/17/20 12:58:10       1   999       2    57
#6 02/17/20 12:58:15       1    61       3    87
```